# JPA vs JDBC vs NoSQL for MMORPG

Tags: java, jpa, jdbc, nosql, rdbms

We are developing a 2D MMORPG space shooter using Libgdx/Netty and we've faced a question we can not resolve concerning the data.

- If we use JPA and RDBMS we can achieve the ACID and ease the data management code
- If we use JDBC width Spring's support we can benefit in speed but complicate the data management code
- We have no experience in NoSQL development, however would the speed benefit (which is crucial) be so great that we should give up easy querying

We are stuck please help us to decide.

Comment: Is your goal to have maximum performance? Or can you have a ballanced approuch for easy maintenance and learning curve?

Comment: The performance will definitely become crucial at some point, many players sending many data, many updates, many inserts, many selects, too many actually.

Comment: But the part of the most frequently executed queries is far smaller than the whole, do you mean to combine JPA with NoSQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You realize, of course, that JPA uses JDBC.
2. Spring can achieve ACID just as easily as JPA can.  I don't know what "speed" benefit you're referring to.  Development speed?  Transaction speed?  Why does Spring complicate data management code?  This is another incorrect statement.
3. What speed are you asking about for NoSQL?  Development?  Runtime?  There's no ACID with NoSQL.  If that's important to you, why are you even considering it?  NoSQL implies "not relational".  Is your data relational?  If yes, why are you considering NoSQL?

You can't decide performance issues by talking about technologies and guessing.  The only way is to benchmark them and get some real data for the transactions that you really care about.

Write interface-based DAOs, implement using each candidate technology, and measure real results.  That's how to decide on which persistence technology to use.

Which one do you know well?  If no one knows NoSQL, don't use it.  If you don't know JPA, don't use it.  Spring JDBC template lets you write custom SQL with transactions.  If you already know relational databases and Spring well, why wouldn't you just use that?

Comment: Thank you Duffymo, yes on the other hand ACID is very important, you mean that runtime performance can be achieved with proper transactions and combining JPA with JDBC?

Comment: No, runtime performance can be achieved by creating a performant schema, indexing properly, and writing efficient queries.  You are so obsessed with running through your technology alphabet soup that you have no clue about what's important.

Answer (score 2):

> We are stuck please help us to decide.

It for sure depends on requirements. And now what i think. If the main goal is performance i suggest you to implement own `ORM`, because you will gain total control over queries, mainly you can optimize all your queries for specific requirements.

I don't say that `JPA`, `EclipseLink` or another framework is wrong definitely no but the most of `ORM` frameworks are designated mainly for goal to be independent on database layer so application is independent on datasource type but for sure you can achieve it by implementations of proper datasource design patterns i.e. `AbstractDAOFactory`, `Mappers` etc.

I have to mention also that main disadvantage of own `ORM` is that implementation takes a lot of time but if you want to create good, efficient and working project, it must takes some time.

For this is many views, somebody recommend you to use `JPA`, `Spring` or `JDBC`(where `JDBC` is for sure faster as `JPA`) and somebody prefer own `ORM`. I think an experience gained from more developers should be enough.

And if you want to use technology, use technology you know.

Comment: Thank you Sajmon, and what about NoSQL?

Comment: @OneMoreVladimir i don't have much experience with noSQL but i think it's not a win for you an usage of noSQL. If you data require relational model, noSQL is not good to use.